# JavaScript updates a page instead of updating a field

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

An original page url is `http://localhost:8080/appname/help.action`
This page contains a form

```
<div id="message"></div>

<form id="help_form" name="help_form" onsubmit="return validate_help_form()">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

a script

```
function validate_help_form() {

    if ( ... ) {
            ...
            return false;
    }

    $.ajax({

        url : 'http://localhost:8080/appname/question',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(result) {    
            console.log('^^^^^^^^^');     
            $('#message').text(result);
        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Unable to receive result. ' + thrownError);
        },
    });

}
```

a servlet is fairly simple

```
logger.info("-----------");

try {
    response.getWriter().append( "a servlet result" );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is when ajax request works then the original page ruqested again by path `http://localhost:8080/appname/help.action. But i want to update a field message with ajax result.
So in a console I get

```
^^^^^^^^^
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/my-mates-ajax/help.action?username=...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return validate_help_form();">
```

Basically you need to first prevent form from submitting then you can perform the operation. Otherwise the form will be submitted along side the ajax request.